# Php sessions boolean always true

Tags: php, session

Im creating a session in the index which is where the login process happens, i then save "username, IsAdmin, logged, first_name,last_name" to the session.

```
 session_start();
$_SESSION["logged"] = FALSE;

$logged = TRUE;             
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
$_SESSION["IsAdmin"] = $IsAdmin;
$_SESSION["logged"] = $logged;
$_SESSION["first_name"] = $first_name;
$_SESSION["last_name"] = $last_name;
header("Location:home.php");
```

If the user is logged in i want to display the homepage which it does, but it always displays the page even if the user isn't logged in.

When i change the if statement to false the page hides properly, so it must be the value of it.

But all the other variables get passed along the session fine.

```
<?php 
    Include('../connect.php');
    session_start();

    $IsAdmin = FALSE;
    $logged = FALSE;
    $username = "";

    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    $IsAdmin = $_SESSION["IsAdmin"];
    $logged = $_SESSION["logged"];
    $first_name = $_SESSION["first_name"];
    $last_name = $_SESSION["last_name"];
    ?>

    <?php if(logged == TRUE) :?>
    <?php Include('../navigation.php'); ?>

     //CODE TO SHOW WHEN LOGGED INA

    <?php Include('../footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I had to get rid of a load of html due to indentation problem apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `$` before variable name. So it should look something like this,

```
 <?php if($logged == TRUE) :?>
```

When you use logged without **$** like this `logged == TRUE`, it takes logged as constant variable. And as it would not be defined it won't be equal to `TRUE`.

Comment: Oh dear, thanks. Cant believe i missed that.

Comment: Yeah it happens :)

Comment: I'll accept your answer when i can